# Screen rotation issue, error "app.g.i.vb"

Tags: vb.net, xaml, uwp

I have a main page in xaml project which I have deployed code to get screen properties. While I rotate the screen it accordingly changes the values for page. However when I put the same code to other .xaml page which is started from main page(frame.navigate) it opens "app.g.i.vb"  in visual studio and highlights" **Global.System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()**" in code. When I rotate mobile device screen does not rotate however the second page is opened and properties are shown. Please help to resolve the problem. Thank you very much. My codes is as below:

```
 Private Sub ScreenAnalysis(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged, Me.Loaded

    Dim PageWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width
    Dim PageHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height
    Dim ScreenWidth = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView.ScreenWidthInRawPixels()
    Dim ScreenHeight = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView.ScreenHeightInRawPixels()
    Dim ScreenScale = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView.ResolutionScale()
    Dim ScreenOrientation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView.CurrentOrientation()



    screenproperties1.Text = "<--Page Properties-->" & vbCrLf & "Width: " & PageWidth & vbCrLf & "Height: " & PageHeight & vbCrLf & "<--Screen Properties-->" & vbCrLf & "Windth: " & ScreenWidth & vbCrLf & "Height: " & ScreenHeight & vbCrLf & "<--Other--> " & vbCrLf & "ScreenScale: " & ScreenScale & vbCrLf & "Screen Orientation: " & ScreenOrientation
End Sub
```

The "app.g.i.vb" content is as below:

---

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Namespace Global.Mechanical_Engineering_Tools

#If Not DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN Then
Public Class Program

    <MTAThread()> _
    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks", " 10.0.17.0")>  _
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
    Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start(Function(p) New Global.Mechanical_Engineering_Tools.App())
    End Sub

    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks", " 10.0.17.0")>  _
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
    Sub Program
    End Sub

End Class
#End If


<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>  _
Partial Class App
    Inherits Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Application

    Private _contentLoaded As Boolean
    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks", " 10.0.17.0")>  _
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
    Public Sub InitializeComponent()
        If _contentLoaded Then
            Return
        End If
        _contentLoaded = true

#If Debug AndAlso Not DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BINDING_DEBUG_OUTPUT Then
        AddHandler Me.DebugSettings.BindingFailed,
            Sub(Sender As Global.System.Object, bindingFailedArgs As Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.BindingFailedEventArgs)
                Global.System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bindingFailedArgs.Message)
            End Sub
#End If

#If Debug AndAlso Not DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION Then
        AddHandler Me.UnhandledException,
            Sub(sender As Global.System.Object, unhandledExceptionArgs As Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
                If Global.System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached Then
                    Global.System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
                End If
            End Sub
#End If
    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: The app.g.i.vb is a generated file. Close it. Delete it by clearing the obj folder. Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on, but when I get errors raised from a [pagename].g.i.[language] file, it is usually because I have an issue with my data bindings. Perhaps double-check those? This is a generated file you are getting the error from, which means the issue is likely something in the connections between the two files (such as a .XAML and a .VB), that the compiler cannot catch (such as certain databinding issues).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem is with event type that is sizechanged and loaded events cannot be run together:

```
Private Sub ScreenAnalysis(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged, Me.Loaded
```

Because **sizechanged** required 'SizeChangedEventArgs', but **Loaded** required 'RoutedEventArgs'